Update Contact doesn't update the contact that in the journey

Currently, I have a journey setup like in the pic. I submit new data to Journey03Users data extension via API and trigger email sending. I hope that when the user opens the received mail, it will trigger an update on the newly created data. But it didn't update.
Does anybody know how the Update Contact activity can update the running data?
Thank you.
